# How to count the number of different elements in a matrix? C programming language

Tags: c, matrix

I have an integer matrix and need to count the number of different integers besides 0 present in the matrix.
For example, in this one,

0 0 1 0
3 0 0 0
0 7 7 7
9 0 0 7

the program should give as result 4, because you can find 4 different integers apart from 0.
Keep in mind that I have to apply this to a matrix which is initialized this way:

```
celula ** matrizInit(int linhas, int colunas){
    int i, j;
    celula ** matriz;

    matriz = (celula **)malloc(sizeof(celula)*linhas);
    for(i = 0; i < linhas ; i++){
        matriz[i] = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula)*colunas);
        for(j = 0; j < colunas; j++){
            matriz[i][j].linha = 0;
            matriz[i][j].coluna = 0;
        }
    }
    return matriz;
```

}

And each integer field can be accessed using matriz[i][j].[INSERT_FIELD_OF_THE_STRUCTURE].
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a job for a Hash Set, you loop through the elements, add them to the Set then get the count/size/length of the Set.

Comment: What's your question? Do you want us to write the whole program for you?

Comment: `(celula **)malloc(sizeof(celula)*linhas);` ->  `(celula **)malloc(sizeof(celula*)*linhas);`

Comment: use hash, or it is scanned post sorted sequence of work.

Answer (score 1):

If the integers you're looking for range from 1 to 9, my idea would be to get an array and store there the occurrences, then loop through the array counting them.

```
bool inMatrix[9] = {false};
```

So if you found the number 5, you'd flag the position 4 (since in C arrays start at 0, which we'll leave for 1).

```
inMatrix[number-1] = true;
```

Then loop the occurrences array and count the trues

```
for (occurrences=0,i=0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (inMatrix[i]) occurrences++;
}
```

And you have the number in occurrences. Voilà.

But if the integer range is wide, you'll definitely have to store all the numbers in a set, restricting repeated numbers and then count the elements of the set.